# Illegal escape character java

Tags: java, netbeans

I have this code

```
 stdin.println("for /r %i in (cdm.jar) do xcopy /Y \"%i\"\ \"\%\userprofile\%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\"");
```

but it causes an error: `illegal escape character`

Comment: Have you tried reducing the string to smaller parts, and seeing which character it is that's illegal?

Comment: why are you escaping a whitespace, a "u", and %?

Comment: voting to close this due to "simple typographical error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
stdin.println("for /r %i in (cdm.jar) do xcopy /Y \"%i\" \"%userprofile%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\"");
```

As my comment stated: dont escape the whitespace, the "u" and the "%".

Comment: @LetalGamer please Click on the checkmark on the left of the answer to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You're escaping `%`,`u` and `whitespaces` (which you should not) and not escaping `\` (which you should).

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("for /r %i in (cdm.jar) do xcopy /Y \"%i\" \"%userprofile%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\"");
    }
}
```

This prints the expected output of,

`for /r %i in (cdm.jar) do xcopy /Y "%i" "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`